# Java quicksort - is it possible to compare objects without using a comparator?

Tags: java, quicksort, comparator

Is there a way to quickSort the elements of an array in an `ArrayList` and at the same time
change the order of the `ArrayList` based on the array sorted without using the `Comparator<>` function?

```java
    public ArrayList<PatientArray> ageSorter(ArrayList<PatientArray> pa) {
        if (pa.size() <= 1) {
            return pa;
        }

        ArrayList<PatientArray> sorted;
        ArrayList<PatientArray> smaller = new ArrayList<PatientArray>();
        ArrayList<PatientArray> greater = new ArrayList<PatientArray>();

        PatientArray middle = pa.get(0);
        int i;
        PatientArray j;
        for (i = 1; i < pa.size(); i++) {
            j = pa.get(i);

            if ((new SortAge().compare(j, middle)) < 0) { // this object comparator
                smaller.add(j);
            } else {
                greater.add(j);
            }
        }
        smaller = ageSorter(smaller);
        greater = ageSorter(greater);
        smaller.add(middle);
        smaller.addAll(greater);
        sorted = smaller;

        return sorted;
    }

    class SortAge implements Comparator <PatientArray>{
    public int compare(PatientArray a1, PatientArray a2){
        return a1.age-a2.age;
    }
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking but the fact that your class implements Comparator is incidental. The interface isn't adding anything in your example. `compare` can just be a method inside the same class as `ageSorter`, or you can do the `a1.age-a2.age` inline in the if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to avoid use of a `Comparator` would be to perform the comparison yourself directly in your quicksort code:

```
if (pa.get(i).age < middle.age)
```

While you haven't asked for general review comments, I'll note that there are lots of unnecessary commands in your code.

```
public ArrayList<PatientArray> ageSorter(ArrayList<PatientArray> pa) {
    if (pa.size() <= 1) {
        return pa;
    }

    ArrayList<PatientArray> smaller = new ArrayList<PatientArray>();
    ArrayList<PatientArray> greater = new ArrayList<PatientArray>();

    PatientArray pivot = pa.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < pa.size(); i++) {
        if (pa.get(i).age < pivot.age) {
            smaller.add(j);
        } else {
            greater.add(j);
        }
    }
    smaller = ageSorter(smaller);
    greater = ageSorter(greater);
    smaller.add(middle);
    smaller.addAll(greater);
    return smaller;
}
```

Also note that typically quicksort is implemented so that the sorting is done in-place - i.e. without creating new arrays.

As @Holger points out in comments below, choice of pivot (as first element) is also poor. The reasons, and alternatives, are explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot)

While technically your algorithm is quicksort it's probably not quick.

Comment: Besides the issue of creating new `ArrayList` instances, using the first element of the (sub)list as pivot raises the likelihood for running into the worst case in real life scenarios. Just consider what happens when encountering (partially) presorted data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort` method on *List* class introduced on **Java 8**.
So your method will be as follow:

```
public List<PatientArray> ageSorter(ArrayList<PatientArray> pa) {
   pa.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.age));
   return pa;
}
```

Comment: I suspect OP wants to actually implement a QS algorithm rather than just call `sort`.

Comment: Yes, I want to apply a quick sort algorithm to my Array List but without the use of a comparator to compare my objects